# How to open this switch/fuse box

Tags: fuses

This is a power switch from a vacuum cleaner, specified as 8A / 250~, which I suspect contains a fuse that has blown. The plastic case has four "tongues" on the sides, but I can't figure out how to open the thing, or what tool I would need to release the fuse.[image]

I tried to push a tongue "inwards" by applying force either on the upper and lower part, but that doesn't seem to work.

The box reads "NOVA KAN-J4" and beneath "T85 8(8)A/250V~".

Comment: What lead you to the conclusion it contains a fuse?

Comment: It's most likely just a switch. These tend to fail after awhile on a vacuum due to the high currents and motor inductance. Suggest trying to find a similar replacement. Finding the exact model is generally quite difficult but there do seem to be some around.

Comment: @winny well I thought there must be a fuse _somewhere_ in the vacuum cleaner, but I haven't found any, so assumed it's embedded with the switch. The only other electrical component I can see that might be involved is a triac (BTA12-600B) which I guess is used for motor speed control or something?

Comment: No, not in EU at least. It only needs to fail in a safe manner. The TRIAC is most certainly for speed control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switch has most likely failed and won’t contain a fuse. Needs a replacement.

Comment: Agreed. As they say "There are no user serviceable parts inside."

Comment: @Elliot: I always take that as a challenge. "Victory to the consumer!"

Comment: @Transistor agreed, but we do that with experience & knowledge... plus a desire to find out how it works...